# Contour integral along elliptic path.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem I have been struggling with while doing a homework assignment for a complex analysis class.

Let $\alpha, \beta: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by

$\alpha(t)=a\cos2\pi t + ia\sin2\pi t$

$\beta(t)=a\cos2\pi t + ib\sin2\pi t$

I have already proven that $\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{z} dz =\int_{\beta}\frac{1}{z} dz=2 \pi i$

I want to use this to show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}=\frac{2 \pi}{ab}$

I can see that

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\beta(t)
\overline{\beta(t)}}$
by letting $\phi(t):[0,1] \to [0,2 \pi]$ and letting $t=\phi(t)$.

I am not sure where to go from here. I think there may be a trick I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(t)=[0,1] \to [0,2\pi]$ and let $t=\phi(t)$

\begin{equation} 2\pi i=\int_{\beta} \frac{1}{z} dz = \int_{\beta} \frac{\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\beta'(t) \overline{\beta(t)}}{ \beta(t) \overline{\beta(t)}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{iab+(b^2-a^2)\sin(t)\cos(t)}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}=\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{iab}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)} + \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{(b^2-a^2)\sin(t)\cos(t)}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}= \end{equation}
\begin{equation} iab\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)} + \text{ln}(a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)) |_{0}^{2\pi}  \end{equation}
Clearly,
\begin{equation} \text{ln}(a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)) |_{0}^{2\pi} =0 \end{equation}
And so we are left with,
\begin{equation} 2 \pi i=  iab\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}\end{equation}
Or simply,
\begin{equation} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}=\frac{2\pi}{ab} \end{equation}